# Computing $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan(-\frac{\pi}{4})+1}{h}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I compute a tan limit with a fraction?

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan(-\frac{\pi}{4})+1}{h}$$

Comment: Do you know what $\tan -\frac{\pi }{4}$ is?

Comment: Its -1 i assume? or 0 ?

Comment: Don't assume. It's a basic value, so you should know it.

Comment: And if you don't know it, you should be able to work it out.

Comment: You should at first learn about [trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) before calculus.

Comment: Was this really the question, or was it $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan(-\frac{\pi}{4}+h)+1}{h}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $ \tan(- \pi /4 )  + 1  = 0$, we have

$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan \left ( \frac{- \pi}{4}  \right )  + 1}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{0}{h}  = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 0 = 0 $$